# Show banner at login with LightDM

Tags: 11.10, lightdm

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and I was wondering if it's possible to show a login banner with text... my company's IT policy requires that some generic text be shown at login. I've seen where you can change the background, so I guess I could make a background with the text in it, but I wanted to see if there is another way.

In Ubuntu 11.04, I was able to do this with the following commands...

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --type string  --set /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/banner_message_text "`cat issue.txt`" 
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --type string  --set /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/banner_message_text_nochooser "`cat issue.txt`" 
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --type boolean --set /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/banner_message_enable true
```

Comment: I've tried asking a more general question about lightdm themes - http://askubuntu.com/questions/69151/how-do-i-set-my-own-theme-in-lightdm-in-11-10 - which if answered well might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers provided to Hamish Downer's question about LightDM themes linked in the comment to my original question include a suitable answer to this question as well.

Comment: If your question is now answered, you should accept this answer so that the question shows up as answered. Or, you can flag it for closure as a duplicate.